# Change width of UICollection view dynamically when x coordinates changes on TouchMoved function

Tags: ios, swift

everybody.
I am making a slide out menu in swift. I have made everything working fine. The slide out menu shows when hamburger button is clicked and also when right swipe on the screen is done. Now I want to make the size (width) of a slide out menu change based on the user coordinates on the screen.

The slide out is implemented using collection view on top of a UIView.

To take the user's position from the screen I have used touchMoved function to get user's real-time x value. Is there any method to use this value so that collection's view's width can be changed.

[image: Screen shot]

Any help will be very helpful. If needed I can upload all the codes. Changing the anchor size also didn't help.

MoreOptionsViewController.swift

```
    override init() {
    super.init();

    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    collectionView.register(MoreOptionsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId);

    getData();
}

func showMoreOptions(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        window.addSubview(view);

        view.setAnchor(top: window.topAnchor, bottom: window.bottomAnchor, left: window.leftAnchor, right: window.rightAnchor);
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapOutside)));
        view.alpha = 0.5;
        collectionView.alpha = 1;

        window.addSubview(collectionView);

        let width = window.frame.width * 0.9;

        //Animate the collection view's width
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.leftAnchor).isActive = true;
            self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.topAnchor).isActive = true;

            self.collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true;
            self.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.heightAnchor).isActive = true;
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}

func handleTapOutside(){
    collectionView.removeFromSuperview();
    view.removeFromSuperview();
}

let view: UIView = {
    let view = UIView();
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return view;
}();

let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout);
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 65/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 0.9);
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return cv;
}();
```

The above code contains the actual collection view to present the slide out menu.

If i try to change the width from touchMoved function I get a lot of error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the collection view's width by updating its frame in your touchMoved function

```
yourCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: <user's_x_scroll_value>, height: height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The problem was caused due to the animation code.

```
func showMoreOptions(xValue: CGFloat){
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
            window.addSubview(view);

            //Display the view beyond the screen. Increase the x coordinates according to the x value of screen
            view.frame = CGRect(x: -window.frame.width + xValue , y: 0, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height);
            view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapOutside)));

            print("View's x value is ", xValue)
            view.alpha = 0.011; //Use minimum alpha value
            collectionView.alpha = 1;

            window.addSubview(collectionView);
            //Same as above view
            collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: -window.frame.width + xValue, y: 0, width: window.frame.width * 0.9, height: window.frame.height);

            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout();
        }
    }
```

Also collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() fixed the problem. Thank you Eli whittle for the help